How does the case (destruct) tactic change the goal?
Updated question:
Let's see the following code.
Inductive Foo : nat -> Prop :=
  | foo : Foo O.
Goal Foo 1 -> (fun n => 1 = n) 1.
intro. case H.
Abort.

After the case H, the goal says 1 = 0.
Next I try the following code.
Inductive Foo : nat -> Prop :=
  | foo : Foo O.
Goal Foo 1 -> (fun n => 1 = n) 1 /\ True.
intro. case H.
Abort.

This time, the goal after case H says 0 = 0 /\ True.
I expect to have 1 = 0 /\ True since I just put /\ True in the conclusion.
Can anyone explain why this strange behavior happens?
Original question:
I'm examining the following code, which demonstrates how we can do the inversion tactic without that.
Inductive even : nat -> Prop :=
  | even_O : even O
  | even_SS : forall n, even n -> even (S (S O)).

Goal ~ even 1.
Proof.
  intro H.
  generalize (eq_refl 1).
  pattern 1 at 2.
  case H.
  - intros. discriminate.
  - intros. discriminate.
Qed.

Before the case H, the proof state is as follows.
H : even 1
============
(fun n : nat => 1 = n -> False) 1

After that, the proof state of the first subgoal becomes the following.
H : even 1
============
1 = 0 -> False

My question is how 1 = 0 is obtained here.
I guess case H replaces the second occurrence of 1 in the original goal with 0 and then simplifies the goal, resulting in 1 = 0 -> False.
However, I cannot figure out why such a replacement happens precisely (and why not for the first occurrence of 1).
Moreover, when trying the following code (which is nonsensical proof), I see that all the occurrences of 1 are replaced by 0, which makes me more confused.
Goal ~ even 1.
Proof.
  intro H.
  generalize (eq_refl (1+1)).
  pattern (1+1) at 2.
  case H.
Abort.

Any idea or a nice document?

You are likely relying on some quirks in Coq's mechanism for generalizing the goal. Your code does not work for me on Coq 8.18.

Really? I checked the code works on Coq 8.18 under wsl installed via opam with OCaml 4.14.2.

The keywords you are looking at are:

dependent inversions
small inversions
dependent pattern matching

The problem you are facing with you case is that Coq cannot do a pattern matching (ie match) on even 1: the indices of the inductive type (the non-constant parameters) must be variables for this, so the most general form of a term in the inductive type.
Your case on even 1 first performs a generalization to even n, and doing so, possibly destroys/forgets information about the specific form of the index n (here 1).
The solution consists in generalizing indeed, but then recapturing your case (n is 1) with a match on the index afterwards, like this:
Inductive even : nat -> Prop :=
  | even_0 : even 0
  | even_SS n : even n -> even (S (S n)).

Fact even_inv n : 
     even n 
  -> match n with
     | 0 => True
     | 1 => False
     | S (S n) => even n
     end.
Proof. now destruct 1. Qed.

Fact not_even_1 : ~ even 1.
Proof. exact (even_inv 1). Qed.


Thanks for the interesting keywords. I basically understand why simply using case does not work and doing some generalization solves the problem. My question is rather the behavior (that looks mysterious to me) of the case tactic than the proof itself.

More specifically, I'm wondering how case changes the goal.

The proof below roughly explains the inner workings of the case you use in your goal: `Inductive even : nat -> Prop :=
| even_O : even O
| even_SS : forall n, even n -> even (S (S O)).
Fact not_even_1 (H : even 1) : 1 = 1 -> False.
revert H; generalize 1 at 1 3.
intros x H.
case H; discriminate.
Qed.
`

Print not_even_1 will give you the generated term.

Suppose your code explains the inner working, how does the my case use determin the occurrences at 1 3 (especially not at 1 2 3)?

case H on even 1 generalizes 1 to n to be able to match on even n. Doing so, it identifies where in the conclusion to transform 1 in n. The previous pattern transforms the goal in (fun n => 1 = n -> False) 1. The generalization is blocked under lambda abstractions, ie under fun ... => ....

If generalization is blocked under lambda, why are all 1s generalized in the my last code (using 1 + 1 instead of 1)?

Well indeed. I do not know what happens in your case of 1+1. Maybe the abstraction is reduced by case. Strange indeed.
